# Assistance needed Switch Statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

i wrote this for class, when you input the letter it should return the gas related to the character. So far i've only been able to get the screen to return "unknown" no matter what can anyone help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
char color; /* input- character indicating gass */

// Color of the gas 
printf("Enter first letter of the color of cylinder > ");
scanf_s("%c",&color); /* scan first letter */

/* Display first character followed by gas */
printf("The gas in the cylinder is %c", color);
switch (color) 
{
    case 'O':
    case 'o':
        printf("Ammonia\n");
        break;

    case 'B':
    case 'b':
        printf("Carbon Monoxide\n");
        break;

    case 'Y':
    case 'y':
        printf("Hydrogen\n");
        break;
    case 'G':
    case 'g':
        printf("Oxygen\n");
        break;

    default:
        printf("unknown\n");
} 

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Try `color = fgetc(stdin);` rather than that `scanf_s`.

Comment: Compiling with gcc using -Wall, I get "warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’"

Comment: `scanf_s()` returns an integer containing the number of arguments that are filled with data. What number does it report? Additionally, can you include the full output that you see when running the program, including your user input? Preferably with the fix of changing `color` to a `char`.

Comment: I commented out the switch statement and when i call upon the stored character it doesn't return anything. just my printf statement without what should've been stored with %c, color .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason you want to use scanf_s()?

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
int color; /* input- character indicating gass */

// Color of the gas
printf("Enter first letter of the color of cylinder > ");
color=getchar(); /* scan first letter */

/* Display first character followed by gas */
printf("The gas in the cylinder is %c\n", color);
switch (color)
{
    case 'O':
    case 'o':
        printf("Ammonia\n");
        break;

    case 'B':
    case 'b':
        printf("Carbon Monoxide\n");
        break;

    case 'Y':
    case 'y':
        printf("Hydrogen\n");
        break;
    case 'G':
    case 'g':
        printf("Oxygen\n");
        break;

    default:
        printf("unknown\n");
}

return(0);
}

c02kt3esfft0:~ mbobak$ ./test
Enter first letter of the color of cylinder > o
The gas in the cylinder is o
Ammonia
c02kt3esfft0:~ mbobak$ ./test
Enter first letter of the color of cylinder > b
The gas in the cylinder is b
Carbon Monoxide
c02kt3esfft0:~ mbobak$ ./test
Enter first letter of the color of cylinder > y
The gas in the cylinder is y
Hydrogen
c02kt3esfft0:~ mbobak$ ./test
Enter first letter of the color of cylinder > g
The gas in the cylinder is g
Oxygen
c02kt3esfft0:~ mbobak$ ./test
Enter first letter of the color of cylinder > q
The gas in the cylinder is q
unknown
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going off an example in the book in which they used scanf_s.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that 'int' is 4 bytes, while the switch is looking at only one byte. Thus the switch may only see the high order 0x00 byte of color. The first thing I'd try is changing color from int to char.

Comment: Tried using char before.

Comment: The scanf() should be writing the character byte into the high end of the 4 byte (probably) integer, and possibly leaving garbage in the other 3 bytes. It didn't work if the **only** change is changing `int color;` to `char color;`? Also, you may be misusing scanf_s. Read the "remarks" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are reading a character into an uninitialized integer which will result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Not a C coder, but it looks to me like you are casting the character to an integer? Which is why it can't switch - it's comparing a char with an int.

Comment: Tried char before didn't work. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

your call to `scanf_s` should be as follows:

```
char color;
scanf_s("%c",&color,1);
```

This worked for me.